# 12.04 display resolution changes after each reboot

Tags: 12.04

I am running 12.04-64bit on a Dell xps15z and the resolution changes after each reboot to 1024x768 .As a result my desktop occupies just 3/4 of my entire screen...I have to manually adjust it through the display option to the max 1366x768 in order for the desktop to occupy the whole display!If you add this to the "system problem detected" that pops up every day I cannot hide my dissatisfaction and frustration about 12.04...

Comment: What display adapter do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

After You log in set required resolution and open Your terminal and write:

```
sudo stop gdm
```

Your graphical environment will be closed. After that press

```
Alt+Ctrl+F1
```

and log in the text mode. Then create Xorg file:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

after that write:

```
reboot
```

Did that help??

Comment: No it didnt since when i did the first step I got this stop: Unknown job :gdm

Comment: What graphical environment do You use?